# Server/client program doesn't work when I add a function in C

Tags: c, file, sockets

I'm making a program that copies a file from client to server. I have to send the length of the file to the server before copying. Both of the programs work fine, until I add `int sizeFile = getSizeFile(originalFile);` in the client part of my program. All of a sudden (after I add the function) the  `while()` loop in my server gets stuck on `recv()`. And the `while()` in my client just loops once and then breaks.

Why does my program work fine until I add the `getSizeFile()` function and how can I solve it?

function:

```
int getSizeFile(FILE* file)
{
    // get file size
    FILE *f = file;
    fseek(f, 0L, SEEK_END);
    int sizeFile = ftell(f);
    return sizeFile;
}
```

server:

```
char ch[70];
printf("where do you want to save it(full path + name): ");
scanf_s("%s", ch, 70);

char c[70];
printf("which file you want to copy(full path + name): ");
scanf_s("%s", c, 70);

r = send(s, c, 70, 0); // B
if (r == SOCKET_ERROR)
{
    printf("2 error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError);
}

FILE* copyFile;
fopen_s(&copyFile, ch, "wb");
if (copyFile == NULL)
{
    printf("Error opening file\n");
}

char buf[BUFSIZE];
size_t size = BUFSIZE;
int counter = 0;

while (1)
    {
        int res = recv(s, buf, BUFSIZE, 0);
        if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("3 error %d\n", WSAGetLastError);
        break;
    }
    size = fwrite(buf, 1, res, copyFile);
    printf("size: %d\n", size);
    printf("res: %d\n", res);
    counter++;
    printf("counter: %d\n", counter);
}
fclose(copyFile);
```

client:

```
    char c[70];
    res = recv(ClientSocket, c, 70, 0); // B
    if (res == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("Server disconeccted\n");
        break;
    }
                
    FILE* originalFile;
    fopen_s(&originalFile, c, "rb");
    if (originalFile == NULL)
    {
        printf("Error opening file\n");
    }

    char buf[BUFSIZE];
    size_t size = BUFSIZE;
    int counter = 0;

    int sizeFile = getSizeFile(originalFile); // <-- this one

    while (size == BUFSIZE)
    {
    size = fread(buf, 1, BUFSIZE, originalFile);
    int r = send(ClientSocket, buf, size, 0);
    if (r == SOCKET_ERROR)
    {
        printf("1 error: %d\n", WSAGetLastError);
        break;
    }
    printf("size: %d\n", size);
    printf("r: %d\n", r);
    counter++;
    printf("counter: %d\n", counter);
}
fclose(originalFile);
```

Comment: Return file pointer to the beginning after fseek and ftell.

Comment: It works now, thank you. Stupid mistake of me

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Would make this a comment since it just riffs off what Alex F said, but not enough reputation. In any case, if you add `rewind(f);` after `int sizeFile = ftell(f);` in `getSizeFile(FILE* file)`, that should solve the issue of not being able to read the file properly.